# Can't remove the value and uncheck the item of checkbox?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Maybe the question is a little bit confusing because I'm confused. The problem I have listed categories in the database I fetched it and create a post. Now I'm trying to edit the post. The categories are in checkbox format if check it adds the `setCategories` state if uncheck it will remove from the state. I have fetched the post and saved categories for that particular post. I've shown them checked. Now I'm trying to change the categories I've added. I'm successful to add more but cannot remove it as well am unable to uncheck the checkbox. Please check this code...

### I'm highlighted the onChange part with dashes

### here is code

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { Alert, Button, Card, Container, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    import { toast, ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
    import { listCategory } from '../actions/categoryActions';
    import { listPostDetails, updatePost } from '../actions/postActions';
    
    const EditPost = ({ history, match }) => {
      const postId = match.params.id;
    
      const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
      const { userInfo } = userLogin;
    
      const categoryList = useSelector((state) => state.categoryList);
      const { categories: cateList } = categoryList;
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!userInfo) {
          history.push('/login');
        }
    
        if (!post || post._id !== postId) {
          dispatch(listPostDetails(postId));
        } else {
          setCategories(post.categories);
          console.log(categories);
        }
        dispatch(listCategory());
      }, [dispatch, history, userInfo, post, postId, categories]);
    
      const resetHandler = () => {
        setTitle('');
        setImg('');
        setCategories('');
        setDesc('');
      };
    
      const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(updatePost(postId, title, desc, img, categories));
        resetHandler();
        history.push('/my_posts');
      };
    
      return (
        <div className=" createPost mt-4 py-4">
          <ToastContainer />
          <Container>
            <h2>EDIT POST</h2>
            <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
              <Form.Group controlId="category" className="mb-2">
                <Form.Label>Select Categories</Form.Label>
                <br />
                {cateList?.map((cate) => (
                  <Form.Check
                    inline
                    key={cate._id}
                    type="checkbox"
                    label={cate.name}
                    checked={categories.includes(cate.name)}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      if (e.target.checked) {
                        setCategories([categories.push(cate.name)]);
                      } else {
                        setCategories(
                          categories?.filter((cat) => cat !== cate.name)
                        );
                      }
                    }}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  />
                ))}
              </Form.Group>
              <Button
                type="submit"
                variant="success"
                style={{ letterSpacing: '2px', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                UPDATE
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </Container>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default EditPost;
```

Comment: `cat` in `categories?.filter((cat) => cat !== cate.name)`  should be `cate`?

Comment: @syltai `cate` name will conflict I've already use `cate` will mapping the `categoryList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is on `useEffect` method you are `console.log(categories)` it keeps on refreshing the state and not allowing you to add or remove items. first remove the `console.log(categories)` and also `categories` dependencies from `useEffect` and use this `setCategories([...categories, cate.name]);` instead of this `setCategories([categories.push(cate.name)]);`. You shouldn't change `categories` directly

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change `categories` directly. So, instead of

```
setCategories([categories.push(cate.name)]);
```

try

```
setCategories([...categories, cate.name]);
```

Comment: I was using previously that showed me but it's not working in case of adding the push one is working fine but the problem removing one. I can't remove a category anymore. This line works for me  while I'm creating but these lines not working on editing  `setCategories([...categories, cate.name]);`

Comment: That is why used push method its allow me add more but the filter method can't allow me to remove is there any other way to remove